# PHP Autoloading

Tags: php, autoload

I've been looking around quite a bit and can't find a concise answer to this question anywhere- perhaps those of you with more experience autoloading than myself could shed some light. Pretty simple question:

I wrote a simple `autoloader`:

```
function __autoload($className){
    $className = BASEDIR . "include/class/" . str_replace("_", "/", $className) . ".php";
    require_once($className);
}
```

Where `BASEDIR` is the base project directory. Works great including classes- go figure.
However, when I go to include classes that extend other classes, it starts to break.

Per the suggestions on this site, I'm using `PEAR` naming conventions for my classes. So my "Event" class (describing an actual event like a party) lives here:

```
include/class/Event/Event.php
```

The actual class name is "Event".

When autoloading the class, I reference it like so:

```
new Event_Event();
```

The autoloader turns that into:

```
"include/class/Event/Event.php";
```

The problem comes when `Event` is extended by some other class utilizing this naming convention.
I'm using, for example:

```
class EventInstructed extends Event_Event
```

The autoloader knows where to look, but since my Event class name is "Event" and not "Event_Event", it is trying to look for the wrong class and can't find it.

The question therefore is, how do I utilize the pear naming conventions correctly, or should I do extra parsing in my autoloader to fix my issue? Explode the string on underscores, grab the class name and use that instead?

Naming conventions are here:
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php

Thanks!!

**edit**

My final solution was as mentioned in the accepted answer. Classes are in the hierarchy as such:

```
include/class/Event/Event.php
include/class/Event/Lesson.php //  <-- extends Event
```

Inside the Event file:

```
abstract class Event_Event{
    //Class code....
}
```

Inside the Lesson file:

```
class Event_Lesson extends Event_Event{
    //Class code....
}
```

And finally, the __autoload function:

```
define("BASEDIR", __DIR__ . "/");

function __autoload($className){
    $className = BASEDIR . "include/class/" . str_replace("_", "/", $className) . ".php";
    echo $className . "<br / >";
    require_once($className);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always add the namespace like this:

```
class Event_Instructed extends Event_Event
```

The file name should be `Instructed.php` in this case.

Comment: Actually, it's not a `namespace`, but `pseudo-namespace`. There must be a line.

Comment: Well yes, the whole PEAR library would need an overhaul since PHP 5.2 isn't supported any more, but that's an other question.

Comment: Thanks for that- one more thing. After that, how would you modify the autoload function?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a `namespace`... Like this:

```
namespace Event
{
    abstract class Event {}
    class Lesson extends Event {}
}
```

this shold work just fine with your autoload function.

P.S.: `__autoload` function is deprecated. Try making this:

```
function Autoload ( $Subject )
{ /* ... */ }

spl_autoload_register('Autoload');
```

This way you'll not need the `str_replace` in your `Autoload` function...

You'll also be able to extend in other namespaces..

```
namespace OtherNamespace
{
    class AnotherEvent extends Event\Event {}
}
```